# Can't print some items in a new function

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, callback, request, cheerio

I've created a script in `node` using `request` and `cheerio` to fetch different `titles` and `links` of different posts from it's landing page and then pass those `titles` and `links` in another function so that I can extract the `title` of those `links` from it's inner page along with the profile link to the user created that post which I've defined as `proLink`.

> ***How I can print those `titles`,`links` and `proLink` from within another function using callback?***

I've written so far:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping';

function getposts(callback){
  request(url, function (error,response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      $('.summary .question-hyperlink').each(function(){
        var items = $(this).text();
        var links = $(this).attr("href");
        return callback(items,links);
      });
    }
  });
}
getposts((item,link,callback)=>{
  request(link, function (error,response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      var proLink = $('.user-details > a').eq(0).attr("href");
      return callback(item,link,proLink);
    }
  });
});
```

Once again: I wish to print the three `item`,`link`,`proLink` of them in another function using callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping';

function getposts(callback) {
  request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      $('.summary .question-hyperlink').each(function() {
        var items = $(this).text();
        var links = $(this).attr('href');
        return callback(items, links);
      });
    }
  });
}

function fetch(callback) {
  getposts((item, link) => {
    request(`https://stackoverflow.com${link}`, function(
      error,
      response,
      html
    ) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(link, error.message);
        return;
      }

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var proLink = $('.user-details > a')
          .eq(0)
          .attr('href');
        return callback(item, link, proLink);
      }
    });
  });
}

fetch((item, link, proLink) => console.log({ item, link, proLink }));
```